# How can I predict DNA binding affinities from a protein sequence?

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, proteins

Are there any computational tools to predict the binding affinity to specific DNA motifs from protein domain sequence information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those that come up from a Google search ("predict DNA binding from protein domain tool") seem pretty well suited to your question.

- [BindN](http://bioinfo.ggc.org/bindn/)
- [DNAbinder](http://www.imtech.res.in/raghava/dnabinder/help.html)

Depending on your computational/statistical know-how you might also find these papers relevant

- [Huang *et al*, Predicting and analyzing DNA-binding domains using a systematic approach to identifying a set of informative physicochemical and biochemical properties](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21342579)
- [Gao *et al*, A threading-based method for the prediction of DNA-binding proteins with application to the human genome](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19911048/)

Comment: The OP is not asking to find which residues interact with DNA, but which DNA motifs are preferred by a given binding protein.